# how to find a timestamp in string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am running a sql and retrieving this array:

```
array(
  732 => string '1291385393<>victorias<><><>Application reminder email sent (documentation needed).|1291396439<>smalamatinas<><><>Busy, so will call us on Monday. ' (length=146)
  765 => string '1290005590<>smalamatinas<><><>Waiting for phone number. ' (length=56)
  767 => string '1300373010<>susanm<><><>Email sent 17/3/11 re availability to work|1364469282<>sarahn<><><>emailed. ' (length=100)
)
```

**Unfortunately this is very old code don't hit me for this rubbish kind of coding and string data.** I am thinking this happens when notes are being saved in database and I can't touch them because the system might break.

how do I find dates from current date or(2015) and above in my notes timestamp?
I don't know whether preg_match() would ba good idea?

Or if I could assign my condition into mysql query?

Comment: Look for timestamps, convert to date, check year. Better yet, don't return mucked up strings from your sql. Can't you get the date without all of this other nonsense?

Comment: In other words, pregmatch for sequence of digits the right length, use result to construct a DateTime, compare with DateTime set to 2015-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: why not? you can use preg_match and use the 3rd parameter for the result array. Regexp would be something like (\d{10})

Comment: Why not use SQL to pick up the rows you only need as opposed to post-press them?

Comment: Assuming any longish integer is a timestamp, you look for and extract it (such as with preg_match()), and format with `date('%Y')` or similar to get the year. I would not try directly matching "an integer greater than or equal to X", where X is `2015-01-01 00:00:00` converted to a timestamp.

Comment: @AzizSaleh can you be more specific plz. Do yo have any idea how to assign my condition on notes field in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably these ten-digit integers are *nix timestamps, although you didn't say so explicitly.  You can use MySQL to retrieve a subset of these items as long as you're willing to ignore the timestamps that come after "|" in your data.

For example, this query will do that.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(message) AS timestamp,
       message 
  FROM note
 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(message) >= '2011-01-01'
```

Here's an example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce9761/4/0

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$arr = array(
    "1291385393<>victorias<><><>Application reminder email sent (documentation needed).|1291396439<>smalamatinas<><><>Busy, so will call us on Monday. ",
    "1290005590<>smalamatinas<><><>Waiting for phone number. ",
    "1300373010<>susanm<><><>Email sent 17/3/11 re availability to work|1364469282<>sarahn<><><>emailed. "
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    preg_match("/^\d+/", $value, $m);
    if ( date("Y",$m[0]) >= 2015 ) {
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Iterating through `array`, matching `timestamp` as converting into year and comparing to 2015

Comment: Thank you ToKeN but Ollies job makes more sence to put my conditions in mysql query. I vote up even though your code works and might be a good solution for others

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it:

```
<?php

$source = '1291385393<>victorias<><><>Application reminder email sent (documentation needed).|1291396439<>smalamatinas<><><>Busy, so will call us on Monday. ';

// parse
list($ts,) = explode('|', $source);
$ts = (int)current(explode('<', $ts));

// format
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s A', $ts);

?>
```

Outputs: **03/12/2010 14:09:53 PM**

This will only work if all entries are consistent like that....

---

If the timestamp is at the begnining of every string, then you can do this:

```
$source2 = '1290005590<>smalamatinas<><><>Waiting for phone number. ';
list($ts2,) = explode('<', $source2);

echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s A', (int)$ts2); // Outputs: 17/11/2010 14:53:10 PM
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
if (date('Y', (int)$ts2) > 2015)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you Latheesan Kanes but Ollies job makes more sence and more clean code. I vote up even though your code works and might be a good solution for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here is list of notes and sub notes that are bigger than current time
$notes = array();            
foreach ($userNotes as $key => $value) {
        //get list of notes
        $arr = explode("|", $value);
        foreach($arr as $note) {
                //find timestamp in each note
                preg_match("/^\d+/",$note, $m);
                //if timestamp is bigger than current time
                if ($m[0]> time()){ 
                    $notes[] = $key;
                }
        }
}
//list of timestamps that are bigger than current time
debug($notes);
```